# Find level of categories in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, recursive-query

I have a script to find the hierarchy of a list of categories. However I would need to know the depth of the level to find all corresponding categories. So my question is there a better way to rewrite the code so that it can drill down to the lowest level without my need to specify how deep to go. As the example below, I had to know that the category level goes to 5 level deep to find all categories.

```
WITH rCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.inv_category ic
    WHERE ic.Primary_org_id = 56392

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        t.*,
        r.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.inv_category t
    INNER JOIN rCTE r ON t.Parent_id = r.Category_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    c1.Parent_id, c1.Category_id, c1.Category,
    c2.Category, c2.Category_id, c2.Parent_id,
    c3.Category, c3.Category_id, c3.Parent_id,
    c4.Category, c4.Category_id, c4.Parent_id,
    c5.Category, c5.Category_id, c5.Parent_id
FROM 
    rCTE c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    rCTE c2 ON c1.Category_id = c2.Parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    rCTE c3 ON c2.Category_id = c3.Parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    rCTE c4 ON c3.Category_id = c4.Parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    rCTE c5 ON c4.Category_id = c5.Parent_id
WHERE 
    c1.Parent_id = 0
ORDER BY 
    c1.Category, c2.Category
```

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns, then you need to use "dynamic SQL" where you first compute the number of columns (levels) and then you dynamically assemble a SQL statement with all necessary columns. Alternatively, you could "concatenate" all levels into a single VARCHAR column, but probably this is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want the parent categories in different columns, which makes the task more complicated that it could be.

One option to shorten the query and avoid multiple joins uses conditional aggregation:

```
with rcte as (...)
select
    max(case when level = 0 then parent_id   end) parent_id_0,
    max(case when level = 0 then category_id end) category_id_0,
    max(case when level = 0 then category    end) category_0,
    max(case when level = 1 then parent_id   end) parent_id_1,
    max(case when level = 1 then category_id end) category_id_1,
    max(case when level = 1 then category    end) category_1,   
    ...
from rcte
```

You can add more triplets of conditional expression to manage as many maximum levels as needed; when the actual hierarchy of the product exhausts, the following columns will come out empty.

Another option is string aggregation. This generates a unique column for each original column, with all values concatenated in the order in which they appear in the hierarchy:

```
with rcte as (...)
select
    string_agg(parent_id,      ' > ') within group(order by level) parent_ids,
    string_agg(category_id_id, ' > ') within group(order by level) category_ids,
    string_agg(category,       ' > ') within group(order by level) categories
from rcte
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But not what I am looking for as I need it to spit out the names of the main category followed by all their child sub categories

Comment: @Jay: the first query does that, which less overhead than your solution (no multiple joins). You can just expand the `select` clause with more columns (say, up to `level` 10).

Comment: Otherwise if you want to dynamically create columns depending on the hierarchy depth, then you need dynamic SQL. This is much more complicated (and not initially mentioned in the question).